# Convert local (viewport relative coordinates) to global (layer coordinates)

Tags: javascript, melonjs

I am trying to convert viewport coordinates to the global(layer) coordinates.

I have tried like described in [docs](http://melonjs.github.io/docs/me.Viewport.html#localToWorld), but it seems like doesn't work:

```
var result= me.game.viewport.localToWorld(x,y, me.game.viewport.AXIS_BOTH);
```

I have, working vise versa combination (converting global to local):

```
me.event.subscribe("pointerdown", function (event) {
  // convert the given into local (viewport) relative coordinates
  var pos = me.input.globalToLocal(event.clientX, event.clientY);
});
```

Why I think that me.game.viewport.localToWorld doesn't work?
Because for my entity I have very big difference in coordinates (like more than 200 points), when clicking on it.

Code snippet:

```
game.PlayerEntity = me.Entity.extend({

    /**
     * constructor
     */
    init:function (x, y, settings)
    {
        var self=this;
        self.leftMouseClicked=false;
        me.event.subscribe("pointerdown", function (event) {
            if(!self.leftMouseClicked) {
                var result= me.game.viewport.localToWorld(self.pos.x,self.pos.y, me.game.viewport.AXIS_BOTH);
                console.log(result);
                console.log(event.clientX);
                console.log(event.clientY);
                self.leftMouseClicked=true;
            }

        });
...
```

So my question is:

How can I convert viewport coordinates to layer one, something similar like we have for converting global to local?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, it was getting offset from **me.game.viewport.pos**.

Result code:

```
var self=this;
me.event.subscribe("pointerdown", function (event) {
        //me.game.viewport.pos -- offset
        var pos = me.input.globalToLocal(event.clientX, event.clientY);
        self.mouseXCoord = pos.x+me.game.viewport.pos.x;
        self.mouseYCoord = pos.y+me.game.viewport.pos.y;
});
```